# How to find out current font used in my Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fonts

How to find out current font used in my Emacs?

Answer (score 60):

In my version of Emacs, I can get the information by entering <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-font`.

Comment: When doing that, it prompts `Font name (default current choice for ASCII chars): ` What does that mean? What should I do there?

Comment: @duperuser: I just hit Enter...

Comment: This is an answer to the second question, but not the first one.  After hitting `Enter`, is the displayed info about the font used for displaying ASCII characters ONLY?  If so, how to find out the fonts used for displaying non-ASCII ones?

Comment: @choroba after hitting enter on M-x describe-font I get "No fonts being used" on the mini-buffer

Comment: @MenelaosPerdikeas: Are you running emacs in a text terminal?

Comment: Emacs 25.1 on Windows says `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable describe-font)`, this worked on Linux though.

Answer (score 23):

Different fonts can be used for different characters and different parts of the buffer.  For a given character, you can find out which font was used by moving point to that character than then doing `C-u C-x =` which will give you all kinds of information about that position in the buffer, including which font was used for it.

Comment: What command is "C-u C-x =" a shortcut to?

Comment: Well, `C-x =` is bound to `what-cursor-position`, but when called with a `C-u` prefix, it mostly delegates the work to `describe-char`.

Comment: So without using any keyboard shortcut, how to do the same thing?

Comment: If you limit yourself to the `M-x` shortcut, it would be `M-x describe-char RET`.

Comment: So why is `C-x =`/`what-cursor-position` not used?

Comment: You can use that as well, but then you need to pass the `C-u` prefix: `C-u M-x what-cursor-position RET`, otherwise you'll get just very brief data in the echo area, and this doesn't include any font information.

Comment: What confuses me is that none of your suggestions include both `what-cursor-position` and `describe-font`.

Answer (score 17):

You can just evaluate

```el
(face-attribute 'default :font)
```

To evaluate a sexp, do `M-:`, type/paste the above sexp in there and hit enter.

Answer (score 4):

Place cursor on text which you want to customize and run `M-x describe-face`.

It will give you information how this font was set, i.e. `markdown-pre-face`. You can then see that it inhertis from `markdown-code-face` which inherits from `fixed-pitch`.

And this is how you can set it:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "Source Code Pro"
                    :height 130
                    :weight 'normal
                    :width 'normal)
(copy-face 'default 'fixed-pitch)
```

Restart Emacs after setting it.

Comment: Does this not need to be saved in some init file before restarting?

Comment: @MiserableVariable yes

Comment: Place it into ~/.emacs.d/init.el and adjust the height to you liking.